# ipad keyboard resize problem

Tags: iphone

I have a "new message" view controller in my app (just like the system sms app) where there are two textfields, one for receivers and one for the message content. The problem is when I switch between the two textfields, the keyboard may resize (depending on the input method), and **I don't get any keyboard notifications.** This is rather embarrassing since the keyboard may cover the textfield, which is not what i want. How can I fix this?

thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use a scrollView to avoid the keyboard covering the textfield, though this doesn't address the larger issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can set your controller as the delegate of your text fields and when textFieldShouldBeginEditing: or textFieldDidBeginEditing: is called, perform any necessary manipulations to your view to make sure the textField is visible.

Comment: i sure can implement the delegate, the problem is i cannot get the new keyboard size since there is no notification, put in another way, how can i know the keyboard size without looking at the notifications?

Comment: Relying on the size that is passed with the keyboard notifications is probably the safest bet since the size will be different based on what the user's language, locale, or other factors affecting the keyboard size are set to.  There may be other ways to reliably get the keyboard size, but I'm not familiar with them.